# How to solve this "parse and balance angle brackets" problem? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, stack

I am struggling with an algorithm problem I saw (and failed). Now, I am trying to understand how to solve the problem.

> Question:
>   Given a string of angle brackets, write a function that add brackets at the beginning and end of the string to make all brackets match. The angle brackets match if for every < there is a corresponding > and for every > there is a corresponding <.
>
> The example input string : ><<><
>
> The output string is <><<><>>

---

My main problem is how to handle multiple < characters in the input string, like <<.  Based on the example given, I will end up with some nested angle brackets, but I am not currently able to figure out how to do this.

I can solve the example input, but when I give it other inputs, the output is not always what I am expecting (input #2 and input #6).  Help would be appreciated.

```
const process = (strInput) => {

  let strOutput = [];
  let stack = [];
  let popped ='';

  for (let i = 0; i < strInput.length; i++) {

    if (strInput[i] === '>') {
      if (stack[stack.length - 1] === '<') {
        popped = stack.pop();
        strOutput.push(popped);
        strOutput.push(strInput[i]);
      } else {
        strOutput.push('<');
        strOutput.push(strInput[i]);
      }
    } else {
        if (stack[stack.length - 1] === '<') {
            strOutput.push('<');
            stack.push(strInput[i]);
        } else {
            stack.push(strInput[i]);
        }

    }   
  }

// After string has been read, check the stack for <

  for (let i = 0; i < stack.length; i++) {
    strOutput.push('>');
  }



  return strOutput.join('');
};

let result = '';

console.log('Input 1: ><<><');

result = process('><<><');

console.log('Output 1: ' + result);
console.log('Expected Output 1: ' + '<><<><>>');

console.log('Input 2: <><<');

result = process('<><<');

console.log('Output 2: ' + result);

console.log('Expected Output 2: ' + '<><<>>');

console.log('Input 3: <><<<>');

result = process('<><<<>');

console.log('Output 3: ' + result);

console.log('Expected Output 3: ' + '<><<<>>>');

console.log('Input 4: <><<<><');

result = process('<><<<><');

console.log('Output 4: ' + result);

console.log('Expected Output 4: ' + '<><<<><>>>');

console.log('Input 5: ><<>');

result = process('><<>');

console.log('Output 5: ' + result);

console.log('Expected Output 5: ' + '<><<>>');

console.log('Input 6: ><<<');

result = process('><<<');

console.log('Output 6: ' + result);

console.log('Expected Output 6: ' + '<><<<>>>');

console.log('Input 7: >>>');

result = process('>>>');

console.log('Output 7: ' + result);

console.log('Expected Output 7: ' + '<<<>>>');
```

Comment: You can just keep a counter. Start at 0, and add 1 for `<` and subtract 1 for `>`. If the number ever drops below zero, or if you end up greater than zero, then the string is unbalanced.

Comment: @Pointy: The problem isn't asking me if the input string is unbalanced or not, which is the common algorithm question.  The problem is asking me to balance the input string.  So, the output string is the corrected string.

Comment: OK, well that seems like it could be ambiguous but I get it.

Comment: @Pointy No worries.  I jotted the problem wording down verbatim after I realized that I wasn't going to get the answer in the time allotted.  The ambiguity of the question is on the original author, not me. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To simplify things, rather than using a stack array, consider using *just* a single number: the number of open `<` tags so far. When a `>` is encountered, if there are no current open tags, add a `<` to the beginning of the string (while keeping the open tag count at 0). Then, at the end, add a number of `>`s matching the number of currently open tags:

```js
const process = (str) => {
  let openCount = 0;
  let additionalLeadingOpenTags = 0;
  for (const char of str) {
    if (char === '>') {
      if (openCount === 0) {
        additionalLeadingOpenTags++;
      } else {
        openCount--;
      }
    } else {
      openCount++;
    }
  }
  return '<'.repeat(additionalLeadingOpenTags) + str + '>'.repeat(openCount);
};

console.log('Input 1: ><<><');

result = process('><<><');

console.log('Output 1: ' + result);
console.log('Expected Output 1: ' + '<><<><>>');

console.log('Input 2: <><<');

result = process('<><<');

console.log('Output 2: ' + result);

console.log('Expected Output 2: ' + '<><<>>');

console.log('Input 3: <><<<>');

result = process('<><<<>');

console.log('Output 3: ' + result);

console.log('Expected Output 3: ' + '<><<<>>>');

console.log('Input 4: <><<<><');

result = process('<><<<><');

console.log('Output 4: ' + result);

console.log('Expected Output 4: ' + '<><<<><>>>');

console.log('Input 5: ><<>');

result = process('><<>');

console.log('Output 5: ' + result);

console.log('Expected Output 5: ' + '<><<>>');

console.log('Input 6: ><<<');

result = process('><<<');

console.log('Output 6: ' + result);

console.log('Expected Output 6: ' + '<><<<>>>');
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance...wow, your solution is elegant and a different perspective than my thinking.  I learned something new.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

## Swift Version

Helps for reference

```
//  Input: "><<><"
//  Output: "<><<><>>"

class Angles {

func addAngles(angles: String) -> String {

var openingCount = 0
var leadingOpenCounts = 0
var newAngles = ""

newAngles = angles

print("New angles \(newAngles)")

for c in newAngles {


    print("Char = \(String(c) )")

    if String(c) == ">" {

        if openingCount == 0 {
            leadingOpenCounts = leadingOpenCounts + 1
        }
        else {
            openingCount = openingCount - 1
        }

    }
    if String(c) == "<" {
        openingCount = openingCount + 1
    }

}

print("LeadingOpenCounts ***** = \(leadingOpenCounts)")
print("OpeningCount ***** = \(openingCount)")
print("Required Closing Count ***** = \(openingCount)")

for _ in 0..<leadingOpenCounts {

    newAngles = "<" + newAngles
}

for _ in 0..<openingCount {
    newAngles.append(">")
}

print(newAngles)
return newAngles
}

}

let angles = Angles()
//><<><
// ><<<>>>
angles.addAngles(angles: "><<><")
```

Answer (score 1):

Java Version

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "><<><";

    int openCount = 0;
    int additionalLeadingOpenTags = 0;

    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (c == '>') {
            if (openCount == 0) {
                additionalLeadingOpenTags++;
            } else {
                openCount--;
            }
        } else {
            openCount++;
        }
    }

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    while (additionalLeadingOpenTags > 0) {
        result.append("<");
        additionalLeadingOpenTags--;
    }
    result.append(s);
    while (openCount > 0) {
        result.append(">");
        openCount--;
    }

    System.out.println(result.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Python Solution**

```html
import itertools



fd = "><<><"



def solution(fd):
    count = 0

    additionalLeadingOpenTags = 0
    for x in fd:
        if x == ">":

            if count ==0:
                additionalLeadingOpenTags+=1
            else:
                count -=1
        else:
            count+=1


    return ("".join(list(map(str.lower,itertools.repeat("<", additionalLeadingOpenTags)))) + fd +"".join(list(map(str.lower,itertools.repeat(">", count)))))
```